# How can a vhost context rewrite rule prevent an earlier server context rewrite rule from running?

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite

I have this rewrite rule early in the server context.  Well before any vhosts.  It works as expected except when a certain rewrite rule in vhost context is run.  Then this rule is missed.
I did not expect any rewrite rules in a vhost context to have impact on rewrite rules in the server context.  Especially when the server context rewrite rules are much earlier in the config.

```
# Remove Leading WWW and Retain http or https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The rule in vhost context that prevents the above rule from running is a rewrite to run a shell script (cgi).

```
# Run Shell Script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !${regex} [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /cgi-bin/SCRIPT.sh?${QUERY_STRING} [PT,E=dontlog,L,END]
```

There are other rewrite rules in the vhost context.  But only this one seems to prevent the server context rewrite rule from running.

Comment: Do the other, non-conflicting vhost context rewrite rules also have `[L]` flags?

Comment: Yes, most of the rules have the L flag.  This is the only rule though that has the PT flag.  But I either I don't understand or I haven't seen anything that describes the PT flag causing this behavior.  In this particular case I actually prefer this behavior rather than sending the 301 response.  But I want to understand what is going on and causing it.

Comment: By the way. I tried removing both the L and END flags.  But the server context rewrite rule still doesn't run if that vhost rewrite occurs.